# Ionic 4 App - works locally but does not work in google play (store)

Tags: ionic-framework

My application, built with Ionic 4, Firebase, Postgres, Nodejs, Express has a client side and a server side.
the auth is implemented using firebase, and some server logics is implemented using an heroku postgres Daas. 
I deployed the server project (the nodejs express with postgres db) to heroku. it works well (tested in postman).
but when I enter the app via google play (app store),
It shows blank white screen, and nothing happens.
the app works locally on my android machine (tested with devapp), works in browser, the server is tested, and client is tested too.
the only thing that does not work is the deployment to google play

Comment: You should have an error somewhere, have you tried chrome inspect to access the console of you android device's webview?

Comment: have you tested it on an android device? are you using cordova? which version?

Comment: Hi. how do I access the console of my android device's webview? btw, when I run the app in my android device, it works perfectly, the blank white screen is only happening in the google play (accessing the app via there)

Comment: I use the latest version of cordova, ionic, and latest version of everything basically

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/ for accessing the console, then edit the question if there is an error you can't solve

Comment: I did that. no errors found in the console

Comment: Nothing strange in the Network tab either?

Comment: What happened at the end?

Comment: I neglected the firebase way and went for my own backend implementation (: